# dynamic linking v/s dynamic loading

Tags: operating-system, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I have read quite a lot of sources on this topic but am still stuck at some concepts.

--I understand that in **dynamic linking**, linking is postponed until runtime i.e., we don't know where the library code is going to be placed relative to the main source at compile time. This helps in implementing the shared library concept i.e., the library code being used by some other process can be used by this process.

--What I don't understand is whats happening in **dynamic loading**. Is the linking done statically in this? If it is statically done, then what could be the purpose of postponing loading until run-time? Is this automatic or does the programmer needs to intervene (make some calls to load the library)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are 2 different concepts. I won't elaborate regarding the dynamic linking, your description is pretty sufficient.

**Dynamic loading** means that some part of executable code is loaded not upon program start into the memory but later during the execution, typically upon demand. The code resides in some external library.

Reasons for dynamic loading might be various, usually they will be related to resources utilization - e.g., minimizing the RAM usage during execution, minimizing the loading time upon program start, etc.

Usage of dynamic loading isn't controlled by the OS but rather by the programmer via OS-provided functionality. The code residing in external library, the main program interfaces and loads it at some stage according to the native logic of the program.

Comment: thanx for the answer. So is the linking static in case of dynamic loading?

Comment: @ishan3243 No, it's dynamic linkage in case of dynamic loading. Otherwise the code resides in the same executable which is loaded entirely by the OS to memory. You can look at *dynamic linking* as a means to convey *dynamic loading*.

Comment: According to this link http://www.quora.com/Systems-Programming/What-is-the-exact-difference-between-Dynamic-loading-and-dynamic-linking ...the person has described four combinations of linking and loading.....which one are you talking about? Does the link even correctly describe it?

Comment: @ishan3243 The link is a good reference. I was referring mainly to the dynamic linkage/dynamic loading case since this is the most common and usable scenario (initially I included other cases as well in my answer but removed them later). Static linkage and loading is another common combination but it's out of this question scope, I suppose. The other 2 combinations are more esoteric and less of interest today.

Comment: > "Usage of dynamic loading ... to minimizing the RAM usage during execution"...  

My understanding is that with dynamic loading you could have multiple copies of the library loaded in memory by different programs. Whereas with dynamic linking the OS loads a single copy, which multiple programs can link to. Is this correct? If so doesn't dynamic loading potentially cause more RAM usage, not less?